# Get top 10 airport names from starts and landings

Tags: sql, sql-server

My scenario seems very easy but when I tried to realise it, it got complicated: I want to offer the customer his "Favorite airports".

Maybe I'm just foolish and fail to notice just a triffle…

### What it should do

- `COUNT` the `Start`s and `Landing`s per airport in `Bookings`
- Get `TOP 10` airport `ID`s and `COUNT` used
- Get `Name` from `Airport`

### Tables and columns

Bookings:

- Start_Airport: `int FOREIGN KEY Airports.ID`
- Landing_Airport: `int FOREIGN KEY Airports.ID`

Airports

- ID: `int PRIMARY KEY`
- Name: `varchar`

### Current state

My query looks like this (this is how far I got):

```
SELECT
    ttl.Start_Airport,
    ttl.Landing_Airport
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(Start_Airport) AS Start_Airport_Count,
            COUNT(Landing_Airport) AS Landing_Airport_Count,
            Start_Airport, Landing_Airport
        FROM
            Bookings
        WHERE
            (
                Start_Airport <> 0 OR
                Landing_Airport <> 0
            )
        GROUP BY
            Start_Airport, Landing_Airport
        ) AS ttl
HAVING
  ttl.Start_Airport_Count = MAX(ttl.Start_Airport_Count) OR
  ttl.Landing_Airport_Count = MAX(ttl.Landing_Airport_Count)
```

### Problem

Currently it says that `Start_Airport_Count` and `Landing_Airport_Count` have to be in `GROUP BY` clause but then I get different results from what I expected to get.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the expected output here?  You say "top 10" but  your query has no limiter.  What if you have 2 starting airports with the highest count, but only 1 with the highest count for landing?

Comment: In that case, it doesn't matter. It should just be the overall favorites. It's not necessary to know if the plane started or Landes there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would unpivot and aggregate:

```
select top (10) a.name, count(*)
from books b cross apply
     (values (Start_Airport), (Landing_Airport)) v(airport) join
     airports a
     on v.airport = a.id
group by a.name
order by count(*) desc;
```

I'm pretty sure this is the shortest and most performant method.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand, You need something like:

```
SELECT Airports.name as Airport, t1.cnt as Start_Airport_count, t2.cnt as Landing_Airport_count
FROM (
    select Start_Airport as a_id, count(*) as cnt from  Bookings 
    group by Start_Airport 
) t1
FULL JOIN (
    select Landing_Airport as a_id, count(*) as cnt from  Bookings 
    group by Landing_Airport
) t2
ON t1.a_id =  t2.a_id 
INNER JOIN Airports
ON coalesce(t1.a_id, t2.a_id) = Airports.id
ORDER BY coalesce(t1.cnt,0) + coalesce(t2.cnt,0) DESC 
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stab at this in a vertical format.  I don't see a clean way of doing this horizontally as you could have different counts of favourite departure/arrival points.

I create simple variable tables, count the start/landing occurrences, and then rank those counts in a descending manner (highest=1).

I then output the results for top ranking airports for each group.

```
DECLARE @Bookings TABLE (Start_Airport INT, Landing_Airport INT)
DECLARE @Airports TABLE (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Airports(Id,Name)
VALUES (1,'New York'),
       (2,'Miami'),
       (3,'London'),
       (4,'Sydney'),
       (5,'Tokyo'),
       (6,'Los Angeles')

INSERT INTO @Bookings (Start_Airport,Landing_Airport)
VALUES (1,2),
       (1,3),
       (6,4),
       (6,5),
       (3,2),
       (3,4),
       (3,6),
       (5,3),
       (5,2),
       (4,2)

;WITH X AS
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(2) OVER(PARTITION BY Start_Airport) AS numOfDepartures,
              COUNT(2) OVER(PARTITION BY Landing_Airport) AS numofArrivals
    FROM @Bookings
), Y AS 
    (
        SELECT *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY numOfDepartures DESC) AS rankDepartures,
                  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY numofArrivals DESC) AS rankArrival
        FROM X
    )

SELECT DISTINCT A.Name, numOfDepartures as flightCount, rankDepartures as airportRank, 'Top Departing Location' as Info
FROM Y 
JOIN @Airports A ON Y.Start_Airport=A.Id
WHERE rankDepartures=1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT A.Name, numofArrivals, rankArrival, 'Top Arriving Location'
FROM Y 
JOIN @Airports A ON Y.Landing_Airport=A.Id
WHERE rankArrival=1
ORDER BY Info, Name
```